# Callback to cloud functions/cloud run if timeout happens?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, callback, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I have some cloud run and cloud functions that serve to parse a large number of files that users upload. Sometimes users upload an exceedingly large number of files, and that causes these functions to timeout even when I set them to their maximum runtime limits (15 minutes for Cloud Run and 9 minutes for Cloud Functions respectively.) I have a loading icon corresponding to a database entry that shows the progress of processing each batch of files that's been uploaded, and so if the function times out currently, the loading icon gets stuck for that batch in perpetuity, as the database is not updated after the function is killed.

Is there a way for me to create say a callback function to the Cloud Run/Functions to update the database and indicate that the parsing process failed if the Cloud Run/Functions timed out? There is currently no way for me to know a priori if the batch of files is too large to process, and clearly I cannot use a simple try/catch here as the execution environment itself will be killed.

Comment: The implementation of this will depend on what files are being processed and what data they contain. Without specifics it's hard to provide accurate guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

One popular method is to have a public-facing API location that you can invoke by passing on the remaining queued information. You should assume that this API location is compromised so some sort of OTP should be used. This does depend on some factors, such as how these files are uploaded or the cloud trigger was handled which may require you to store that information in a database location to be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag on the db before you start processing, then after processing, clear/delete the flag. Then have another function regularly check for the status.

Answer (score 0):

No such callback functionality exists for either product.

Serverless products are generally not meant to be used for batch processing where the batches can easily be larger than the limits of the system.  They are meant for small bits of discrete work, such as simple API calls.

If you want to process larger amounts of data, considering first uploading that to Cloud Storage (which will accept files of any size), then sending a pubsub message upon completion to a backend compute product that can handle the processing requirements (such as Compute Engine).

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer. For example, you might be able to achieve that by filtering and creating a sink in the relevant StackDriver logs (where a cloud function timeout crash is to be recorded), so that the relevant log records are pushed into some PubSub topic. On the other side of that topic you may have some other cloud function, which can implement the desired functionality.

Indirect answer. Without context, scope and requirement details - it is difficult to provide a good suggestion... but, based on some guesses - I am not sure that the design is optimal. Serverless services are supposed to be used for handling independent and relatively small chunks of data. If are have something large - you might like to use the first, let's say cloud function, to divide it into reasonably small chunks, so they can be processed independently by, let's say the second cloud function. In your case - can you have a cloud function per file, for example? If a file is too large (a few Gb, or dozen Gb) - can it be saved to a cloud storage and read/processed in chunks, so that the cloud functions are triggered from he cloud storage? And so on. That approach should help, but has a drawback - complexity is increased, as you have to coordinate and control how the process is going...